# how to run mclust faster on 50000 records dataset

Tags: r

I am a beginner, I am trying to cluster a data frame (with 50,000 records) that has 2 features (x, y) by using [`mclust`](http://www.stat.washington.edu/mclust) package.  However, it feels like forever to run a command (e.g.`Mclust(XXX.df)` or `densityMclust(XXX.df)`.

Is there any way to execute the command faster? an example code will be helpful.

For your info I'm using 4 core processor with 6GB RAM, it took me about 15 minutes or so to do the same analysis (clustering) with Weka, using R the process is still running above 1.5 hours. I do really want to use R for the analysis.

Comment: It's hard to optimize a function which you didn't write.  You can use `Rprof` and see if it finds anything, but it sounds like you've got a lot of data and a not-super-fast machine and should just expect it to take awhile.  Consider a big Amazon S3 node.

Answer (score 13):

Dealing with large datasets while using `mclust` is described in [Technical Report](http://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2012/tr597.pdf), subsection 11.1.

Briefly, functions `Mclust` and `mclustBIC` include a provision for using a subsample of the data in the hierarchical clustering phase before applying `EM` to the full data set, in order to extend the method to larger datasets.

Generic example:

```
library(mclust)
set.seed(1)
##
## Data generation
##
N  <- 5e3
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(N)+ifelse(runif(N)>0.5,5,0), y=rnorm(N,10,5))
##
## Full set
##
system.time(res <- Mclust(df))
# >   user  system elapsed 
# > 66.432   0.124  67.439 
##
## Subset for initial stage
##
M <- 1e3
system.time(res <- Mclust(df, initialization=list(subset=sample(1:nrow(df), size=M))))
# >   user  system elapsed 
# > 19.513   0.020  19.546
```

"Subsetted" version runs approximately 3.5 times faster on my Dual Core (although `Mclust` uses only single core).

When `N<-5e4` (as in your example) and `M<-1e3` it took about 3.5 minutes for version with subset to complete.